# netplan error, unknown key nameservers

Tags: networking, netplan

I have an error, but not a spelling error.

Here is my netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens32:
      addresses: [172.16.120.74/16]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.53, 172.16.1.5]
  renderer: networkd
  version: '2'
```

This displays the error:

```
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/99.clw_netcfg.yaml line 3 column 6: unknown key nameservers
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting the renderer and version lines above the ethernets section? Also make sure your indentation is only using spaces not tabs. Run `netplan generate --debug` afterwards to see if you can get a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the netplan error messages often lead you to look at the wrong line. Lay your netplan yaml file out like this and it should all work:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens32:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.120.74/16
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.53, 172.16.1.5]
```

Note that the '-' character of your IP address should be under the second d in addresses from the line above.

Comment: is not worked, same error